# How to choose 2D diagonals of a 3D NumPy array

Tags: numpy, sum, axis, shapes, diagonal

I define an array as :

```
XRN =np.array([[[0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1],
    [0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1],
    [0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1],
    [0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1],],
    [[0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1],
    [0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0],
    [1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1],
    [0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1],],
    [[0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0],
    [0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0],
    [0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1],
    [0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1],]])
print(XRN.shape,XRN)
XRN_LEN = XRN.shape[1]
```

I can obtain the sum of inner matrix with :

```
    XRN_UP = XRN.sum(axis=1)
    print("XRN_UP",XRN_UP.shape,XRN_UP)

XRN_UP (3, 10) [[0 4 1 2 1 3 1 4 0 4]
 [1 4 1 3 0 2 2 3 1 3]
 [0 4 0 4 2 2 2 4 0 2]]
```

I want to get the sum of all diagonals with the same shape (3,10)

I tested the code :

```
  RIGHT = [XRN.diagonal(i,axis1=0,axis2=1).sum(axis=1) for i in range(XRN_LEN)]
  np_RIGHT = np.array(RIGHT)
  print("np_RIGHT=",np_RIGHT.shape,np_RIGHT)
```

but got

```
np_RIGHT= (4, 10) [[0 3 0 3 1 2 0 3 1 2]
 [1 3 2 1 0 1 1 3 0 3]
 [0 2 0 1 1 1 1 2 0 2]
 [0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1]]
```

I checked all values for axis1 and axis 2 but **never got the shape(3,10)** : How can I do ?

```
axis1   axis2   shape
0       1       (4,10)
0       2       (4,4)
1       0       (4,10)
1       2       (4,3)
2       0       (4,4)
2       1       (4,3)
```

Comment: `XRN` is (3,4,10) shape; `XRN_LEN` is 4, so `RIGHT` has len 4.  Your `diagonal` is (10,n) with `n` varying with `i` from 3 to 1.  Sum on the last axis leaves us with a 1d (10,) array.  So that explains the (4,10) shape.  Diagonals on 3d array are tricky to understand, expecially when the dimensions differ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to sum all possible diagonals on the three elements separately. If that's the case, then you must apply [`np.diagonal`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diagonal.html) on `axis1=1` and `axis2=2`. This way, you end up with `10` diagonals per element which you sum down to `10` values per element. There are `3` elements, so the resulting shape is `(10, 3)`:

```
>>> np.array([XRN.diagonal(i, 1, 2).sum(1) for i in range(XRN.shape[-1])])
array([[2, 3, 2],
       [2, 1, 2],
       [1, 1, 2],
       [3, 2, 3],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [2, 3, 3],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0]])
```

Comment: Thanks Ivan , I didnt notice that my XRN_LEN was wrong, it has to be XRN_LEN = XRN.shape[-1].